# Man points to suicide jumper in black and white old clip?

Tags: identify-this-movie, black-and-white

I hope this is the right place for this question:

I recall watching a movie where there was an old black and white clip (perhaps a home video within a movie?) where someone was standing near a large Victorian style building pointing toward the top. On top of the building was the silhouette of a man with his trench coat blowing in the wind. Moments later he slowly leans forward and starts calmly falling to his death.

Alternatively it could have been the guy at the top of the building pointing to something before jumping, but the rest remains the same. The scene was very dark and ominous. I don't know what movie this was in and if anybody recalls this please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This scene is a key scene in the movie [The Game](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119174/combined) where Sean Penn, playing Conrad, buys a thrilling game of survival for his brother's (Michael Douglas, playing Nicholas) birthday. The flashback concerns young Nicholas witnessing the suicide of his father when he was 48 years old, the same age that Nicholas is now celebrating. From [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119174/synopsis):
*The game focuses on a key moment of Nicholas's life when, as a child, he witnessed his father committing suicide by leaping off their family home, the same home Nicholas lives in. Significantly, Nicholas's father took his life on his 48th birthday, the same age as Nicholas is now.*

Comment: Wow, this is precisely what I was looking for I can't believe you got this with so little information.